# Accessing Max Input Delay with C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

I am having trouble obtaining certain data from Windows Performance Counters with C++. I will preface my question by stating that I am new to both C++ and to developing for Windows, but I have spent some time on this issue already so I feel familiar with the concepts I am discussing here.

*Question:*

How do I use Windows PDH (Performance Data Helper) C++ to obtain [Max Input Delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-rdsh-performance-counters)--either per session or per process? Are there certain Performance Counters that are not available outside of perfmon?

*Progress so far:*

I have used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/writing-performance-data-to-a-log-file) example to log some Performance Counters successfully, but the ones I want produce [the error code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/pdh-error-codes) 0xC0000BB8: "The specified object is not found on the system." This confuses me because I can access the objects--"User Input Delay per Process" or "User Input Delay per Session"--fine through perfmon. I even went as far as enabling the counter in the registry as outlined in the article I linked in my question, despite being on a build of Windows 10 that should have it enabled by default. I had to make a small change to get the code to compile, but I have changed only the definition of COUNTER_PATH during my testing because, again, the code works as advertised except when it comes to the counter I want to access. Specifically:

Does not compile:

```
CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH = L"\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time";
```

Does compile and log:

```
CONST wchar_t *COUNTER_PATH = L"\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Timee";
```

OR

```
CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH = const_cast<PWSTR>(TEXT( "\\Processor(0)\\% Processor Time" ));
```

Compiles, but throws error code 0xC0000BB8 at runtime (This is the Counter I want to access):

```
CONST PWSTR COUNTER_PATH = const_cast<PWSTR>(TEXT( "\\User Input Delay per Session(1)\\Max Input Delay" ));
```

The hardcoded session ID of 1 in the string was for troubleshooting purposes, but wildcard (*) and 0 were also used with the same result. The counter path matches that shown in perfmon.

Essentially, all Performance Counters that I have attempted to access with this code--about 5 completely different ones--have successfully logged the data being requested, but the one I want to access continues to be evasive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this same question on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/486192/obtaining-user-input-delay-per-process-with-c.html) and received the answer:

The Performance Counters in question require administrator privileges to access. All I had to do was run this program in administrator command prompt, and that solved my issue.